# Como listar dados de uma api numa activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Opa galera, boa noite

É o seguinte, tenho uma aplicação no android studio onde estou consumindo uma api através do retrofit e gson, conseguir fazer toda a conexão e a funcionalidade de cadastrar está funcionando normalmente. O grande problema é que tenho uma função chamada list onde trás os dados da api, mas não consigo jogar essa list na activity. Segue o código.

*A linguagem é kotlin*

Aqui está a activity onde implemento a fun list e jogo essa mesma função no onCreate da mesma activity para quando rodar o projeto já aparecer listado na tela:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private val clients: MutableList<Client> = mutableListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    list()
}
fun list(){
     val clients: MutableList<Client> = mutableListOf()
     ClientWeb().list({
        clients.addAll(it)
        Toast.makeText(this, "Trouxe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }, {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Falha ao buscar notas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: voce precisa colocar um listiview ou um recyclerview no seu layout e mandar a lista pra um desses componentes
de uma olhada no assunto adapterviews
aqui tem um exemplo em java para adapter com listview https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50020/adapter-numa-listview-no-android-studio para recyclerview veja aqui https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

Você está em dúvida sobre qual componente do layout usar para exibir informações de uma lista?
Se essa for a dúvida, você pode optar por usar um ListView (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView).

Porém eu recomendo fortemente usar um RecyclerView (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=pt-br).

Ambas as opções servem para exibir informações de uma lista na tela.